# Gson Parsing Collection

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have the following JSON response from a service.

```
 {
    "ProductsByCategory": [
    {
    "id": 2593,
    "name": "LeJen Wrap",
    "slug": "lejen-wrap",
    "permalink": "https://shop.vivachoc.com/product/lejen-wrap/",
    "date_created": "2018-05-26T01:20:14",
    "date_created_gmt": "2018-05-26T01:20:14",
    "date_modified": "2018-05-27T13:30:25",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2018-05-27T13:30:25",
    "type": "variable",
    "status": "publish",
    "featured": false,
    "catalog_visibility": "visible",
    "description": "",
    "short_description": "",
    "sku": "",
    "price": "1",
    "regular_price": "",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
    "price_html": "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\">
    ]
    }
```

I'm currently using GSON to parse the response. This is my java code for parsing the Gson. I then use a collection to hold the data following the https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md as a guide.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();    
 Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<ProductsByCategory>>(){}.getType();
 Collection<ProductsByCategory> productItems = gson.fromJson(mMessage, collectionType);
```

The product category class is as follows:

```
public class ProductsByCategory {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    @Expose
    private String slug;
    @SerializedName("permalink")
    @Expose
    private String permalink;
    @SerializedName("date_created")
    @Expose
    private String dateCreated;
    @SerializedName("date_created_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateCreatedGmt;
    @SerializedName("date_modified")
    @Expose
    private String dateModified;
    @SerializedName("date_modified_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateModifiedGmt;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("featured")
    @Expose
    private Boolean featured;
    @SerializedName("catalog_visibility")
    @Expose
    private String catalogVisibility;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("short_description")
    @Expose
    private String shortDescription;
    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("regular_price")
    @Expose
    private String regularPrice;
    @SerializedName("sale_price")
    @Expose
    private String salePrice;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_from")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleFrom;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_from_gmt")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleFromGmt;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_to")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleTo;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_to_gmt")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleToGmt;
    @SerializedName("price_html")
    @Expose
    private String priceHtml;
    @SerializedName("on_sale")
    @Expose
    private Boolean onSale;
    @SerializedName("purchasable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean purchasable;
    @SerializedName("total_sales")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalSales;
    @SerializedName("virtual")
    @Expose
    private Boolean virtual;
    @SerializedName("downloadable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean downloadable;
    @SerializedName("downloads")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> downloads = null;
    @SerializedName("download_limit")
    @Expose
    private Integer downloadLimit;
    @SerializedName("download_expiry")
    @Expose
    private Integer downloadExpiry;
    @SerializedName("external_url")
    @Expose
    private String externalUrl;
    @SerializedName("button_text")
    @Expose
    private String buttonText;
    @SerializedName("tax_status")
    @Expose
    private String taxStatus;
    @SerializedName("tax_class")
    @Expose
    private String taxClass;
    @SerializedName("manage_stock")
    @Expose
    private Boolean manageStock;
    @SerializedName("stock_quantity")
    @Expose
    private Object stockQuantity;
    @SerializedName("in_stock")
    @Expose
    private Boolean inStock;
    @SerializedName("backorders")
    @Expose
    private String backorders;
    @SerializedName("backorders_allowed")
    @Expose
    private Boolean backordersAllowed;
    @SerializedName("backordered")
    @Expose
    private Boolean backordered;
    @SerializedName("sold_individually")
    @Expose
    private Boolean soldIndividually;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    @Expose
    private String weight;
    @SerializedName("dimensions")
    @Expose
    private Dimensions dimensions;
    @SerializedName("shipping_required")
    @Expose
    private Boolean shippingRequired;
    @SerializedName("shipping_taxable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean shippingTaxable;
    @SerializedName("shipping_class")
    @Expose
    private String shippingClass;
    @SerializedName("shipping_class_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer shippingClassId;
    @SerializedName("reviews_allowed")
    @Expose
    private Boolean reviewsAllowed;
    @SerializedName("average_rating")
    @Expose
    private String averageRating;
    @SerializedName("rating_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer ratingCount;
    @SerializedName("related_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> relatedIds = null;
    @SerializedName("upsell_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> upsellIds = null;
    @SerializedName("cross_sell_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> crossSellIds = null;
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer parentId;
    @SerializedName("purchase_note")
    @Expose
    private String purchaseNote;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<Category> categories = null;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> images = null;
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Attribute> attributes = null;
    @SerializedName("default_attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> defaultAttributes = null;
    @SerializedName("variations")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> variations = null;
    @SerializedName("grouped_products")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> groupedProducts = null;
    @SerializedName("menu_order")
    @Expose
    private Integer menuOrder;
    @SerializedName("meta_data")
    @Expose
    private List<MetaDatum> metaData = null;
    @SerializedName("_links")
    @Expose
    private Links links;
```

However, I keep on getting the following error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Am I not following this correctly? I have the following class that wraps the items.

```
public class ProductItems {

    @SerializedName("ProductsByCategory")
    @Expose
    private List<ProductsByCategory> productsByCategory = null;

    public List<ProductsByCategory> getProductsByCategory() {
        return productsByCategory;
    }

    public void setProductsByCategory(List<ProductsByCategory> productsByCategory) {
        this.productsByCategory = productsByCategory;
    }
```

Comment: Any progress? Is your issue resolved or do you still encounter problems?

Comment: Still working on it. I had parked it for a while will look at it again today

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that expects a `JsonArray`, but the provided `JSON` is a `JsonObject`. Take a look yo your `JSON`, at top level you have a `JsonObject` called `"ProductsByCategory"`. So, you need to pass the content of the `JsonObject` "ProductsByCategory" which is a `JsonArray`.

You could do the following:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<ProductsByCategory>>(){}.getType();
Collection<ProductsByCategory> productItems = gson.fromJson(mMessage.getAsJsonArray("ProductsByCategory"), collectionType);
```

If you already have a wrap class ("ProductItems"), you have to fix your code as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ProductItems>(){}.getType();
ProductItems productItems = gson.fromJson(mMessage, collectionType);
```

Comment: I have made the change and i still get the same error. com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Which of two snippets?

Comment: the bottom snippet. For the top snippet, it will not work for the following reason. mMessage is a string and not a JSon Array4:  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
            {

                String mMessage = response.body().string();

Comment: Btw, have you noticed that the JSON seems invalid? This line is oncorrect `    "price_html": "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\">`

Comment: I did not post the whole JSON it exceeds the length of that i can post in a question

Comment: Ok, you could try to do the following: `JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(mMessage);` and check if this works and which kind of dynamic type is `json` variable.

Comment: Tried that method it provides some sense of direction in solving the problem

Comment: Good, post your progress in order to help you better

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the collection in a class that has a single member `ProductsByCategory`:

```
class ProductsByCategoryHolder {
  @SerializedName(“ProductsByCategory“)
  private List<ProductsByCategory> productsByCategory;
}
```

Your code would work, if the collection was the root element of the JSON message, like this:

```
[{
  "id": 2593,
  "name": "LeJen Wrap",
  "slug": "lejen-wrap",
  ...
}]
```

Simply use

```
final ProductItems items = new Gson().fromJson(mMessage, ProductItems.class);
```

To parse the JSON message.

Comment: Why do you try to parse the message directly into the collection type instead of parsing into the `ProductsItem` class?

Comment: @George, I tried `final ProductItems items = new Gson().fromJson(json, ProductItems.class);` and parsed your JSON without problems. As already mentioned the above JSON is invalid due to a missing closing `"` for the `price_html` value.